# How to check if a decimal value from input is greater than a list of decimal

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, decimal

I have a decimal list. I need to find if a `decimal` input is greater than any of the value present in the list.

```
Decimal threshold = 20;

List<Decimal> InputList = new List<Decimal>() { 10, 20, 35 };
```

Please note this input list might have *one or more* items in the list.

I want to check if *one of the items* is greater than the threshold value, then do something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Any`. It checks if at least one element in the list matches the condition.

```
InputList.Any(x => x > threshold);
```

Comment: Thank you will use this trick and let you know in few hours and accept your answer. No exceptions will be thrown if something is empty or  null?

Comment: @Learner If InputList is null then it should throw null reference exception otherwise it won't

Comment: @Learner And if the list is empty, `Any` returns false which I believe is fine in your case. @Reyan maybe you should add an `if` clause to your (valid) answer, `Any` as a statement is not really useful ;)

Comment: @ReyanChougle: Sure, let me veryfiy and let you know, although I came out from office 3.5 hours ago its night here, I would still remote my machine to use your logic and quick round of testing and accept your answer if everything is ok.

Comment: @vc74: Thank you so much thats quite useful to know me being a layman

Comment: @Learner Thanks

Comment: Its 11.10 PM I still connected to my office machine remote and I could get that working through your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with Linq you could write a function like this:

```
private static bool CheckIfLarger(IEnumerable<double> list, double value){
  foreach(var item in list) if(value<=item) return false;    
  return true;
}
```

**Edit:** Explanation: you compare your value to every number in the List and if it is smaller you returne false, since than your number is not smaller than every other number in the List. If this does not occure at all you return true, because obviously it was not smaller than any of the others.

Comment: I think you should invert `true` and `false`?

Comment: No, look at my if-statement. I think it is better to return true if it is larger

Comment: @L.W.: Thank you, but  I cant understand your answer. Einstein says, if a information isn't taught or communicated in the way it can be understood, the person itself hasn't understood it right. Well not on you, but for me being a layman with few years of dev experience with Business Analyst or Tester or program manager skills, I find it hard to understand. Other answer with 5 ratings is so simple although I dont know whats happening inside behind the scenes lol

Comment: Thats true, but its not intended to be like the Linq.Any. I think its a matter of taste.

Comment: If list is empty this code will return true, additionally if the first item in the list is less than the threshold it will return false.

Comment: @BobVale no it will not return false. Value is largen than item, so the if statement will be false and it won't return anything immediatly

Comment: My mistake read the comparison the wrong way round. However for double you should not use an equals due to imprecision you need to take into account Double.epsilon